# Add CSS class to element when using IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I'm trying to fix UI problem that occure only on IE, so I'm trying to figure out if I'm on IE and then add class id to all element that already on class main-content (found im the most of my HTML files).

I want to add script to my index.html (which call to shell, and the shell to all other files).

So on my index.html I added those lines:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
$(function(){
    if(navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident\/7\./)) {
        $('.main-content').addClass('if-ie');
    }


});//]]>
</script>
```

But it doesn't work

It is work if I'm switching the selector to :

```
$('body').addClass('if-ie');
```

So i guess it because I'm trying to get to other files.
There is a solution for that?

Comment: What is `.main_content`? What do you mean by other pages? BTW, looks like an XY problem because anyway you should detect feature support, not browser

Comment: My guess is that nothing in the current document matches the selector `$('.main-content')`. Elements have to be loaded into the DOM before you can select them.

Comment: Instead of hacking this up in JavaScript why not place all your IE specific styles in a `ie.css`, over-writing any styles from your `default.css` and include it in IE browsers only? That way you don't have to keep updating your JavaScript every time you want to change/add something. You can include the file then by placing something similar to this into the `<head>`: `<!--[if IE]>    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="ie.css"><![endif]-->`

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
if ( $.browser.msie ) {
$('.main-content').addClass('if-ie');
}
```

Version and other details

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.browser/

Answer (score 0):

You could use this script to detect Internet Explorer

`var isMSIE = /*@cc_on!@*/false;
if ( isMSIE ) {
  $('.main-content').addClass('if-ie');
}`

http://dean.edwards.name/weblog/2007/03/sniff/